# Decorate an Iterator in PHP - enable skipping

Tags: php, design-patterns, iterator, decorator

I have a class that is basically a decorator for PHP's DirectoryIterator. Each file's contents are processed by the class and then returned by the `current()` method. Currently, when the file is a dot file or the file cannot be processed, I return `false` from the `current()` method. But I would rather like to skip the dot- and unprocessable files, and only return processed data.

P.S. The code below is a simplified  example. I don't want to pre-process all files in the constructor.

```
class Pages implements \Iterator
{
    public function __construct(string $path)
    {
        $this->di = new \DirectoryIterator($path);
    }

    public function rewind() {
        return $this->di->rewind();
    }

    public function current() {
        $file = $this->di->current();
        if($file->isDot()) {
            return false;
        }
        $content = file_get_contents($file->getPathName());
        if($content === 'Cannot be processed!') {
            return false;
        }
        return $content;
    }

    public function key() {
        return $this->di->key();
    }

    public function next() {
        return $this->di->next();
    }

    public function valid() {
        return $this->di->valid();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would think that in your `current` you’d be able to just repeat a call to `$this->di->current()` for your existing `false` conditions. Effectively you’d end up with a `while` loop or similar.

Comment: @Chris Haas - thanks for your suggestion. I posted an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly simplify the code of your own answer by extending the already existing abstract PHP class [`FilterIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/class.filteriterator.php) :

```php
class DirectoryFilterIterator
  extends FilterIterator
{
  public function __construct(string $path) {
    parent::__construct(new DirectoryIterator($path));
  }

  public function accept() : bool {
    $current = parent::current();
    // let's not only ensure it's not a dot but that it's an actual readable file
    if(!$current->isFile() || !$current->isReadable()) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      $contents = file_get_contents($current->getPathname());
      if($contents === 'Some value') {
        return false;
      }
    }
    
    return true;    
  }
}

foreach(new DirectoryFilterIterator('.') as $key => $value) {
  echo "$key -> $value\n";
}
```

As you can also see, instead of merely ensuring that the item is not a dot, I ensure the item is an actual readable file as I think that is a little more robust for your intentions.

---

PS: As your original intention was to create a decorator/wrapper you can of course alter the constructor of `DirectoryFilterIterator` to accept a `DirectoryIterator` instead:

```php
public function __construct(DirectoryIterator $it) {
  parent::__construct($it);
}
```

...and then change the instantiation to:

```php
foreach(new DirectoryFilterIterator(new DirectoryIterator('.')) as $key => $value) {
  echo "$key -> $value\n";
}
```

Comment: Just perfect, I didn't know `FilterIterator` exists

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found this solution, hope someone finds it helpful. One could apply this pattern to any decorated Iterator, effectively ending up with something like a "filtered" iterator.

```php
class FilteredIterator implements \Iterator
{
    protected $currentProcessed = null;
    protected $key = -1; // Keys are maintained by the decorating class

    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator)
    {
        $this->it = $iterator;
    }

    // Iterator interface START -->

    public function rewind() {
        $this->it->rewind();
        $this->forward();
    }

    public function current() {
        return $this->currentProcessed;
    }

    public function key() {
        return $this->key;
    }

    public function next() {
        $this->it->next();
        $this->forward();
    }

    public function valid() {
        return $this->it->valid();
    }

    // <-- Iterator interface END


    protected function forward() : void
    {
        if(!$this->it->valid()) {
            // Stop when iterator is done
            return;
        }
        // Pseudo code, insert expensive processing function here -->
        $content = $this->it->current();
        if($content === 5) {
        // <-- Pseudo code END
            // Skip 
            $this->next();
            return;
        }
        // Update position
        $this->key++;
        // Cache successfully processed step
        $this->currentProcessed = $content;

    }
}

$arrayObject = new ArrayObject([1,2,3,4,5,6]);

$filteredIterator = new FilteredIterator($arrayObject->getIterator());

foreach ($filteredIterator as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' -> ' . $value . "\n";
}

//0 -> 1
//1 -> 2
//2 -> 3
//3 -> 4
//4 -> 6
```